# BigQuery - Alternative method to Positive Lookahead for RegExes

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I've written a RegEx pattern that identifies alpha-characters that are immediately followed by a numeric character, with the intention that it would used in BigQuery's `REGEXP_EXTRACT` function.

Here's the pattern: `([A-Z]|[a-z])*(?=[0-9])`

However, due to BigQuery's use of RE2 expression library, the Positive Lookahead function does not work. What's an alternative method of identifying the numeric character without including it in the extracted string/match?

Use case:

To extract the first 1 or 2 alpha-characters of a UK postcode, e.g.

- `NW`9 9KL
- `M`1 0TE
- `ph`3 2ee
- `N`10 10KE

Comment: Maybe just `^[A-Za-z]+` will do?

Comment: Brilliant - that works - could you explain how it omits the numeric characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(col, '^[A-Za-z]+')
```

The `^[A-Za-z]+` regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z]+` - one or more letters.

Also, if you MUST check for a digit right after the initial letters, you can use a

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(col, '^([A-Za-z]+)[0-9]')
```

The `^([A-Za-z]+)[0-9]` regex matches and *captures into Group 1* the initial letters, and then just matches a digit (with `[0-9]`). The `REGEXP_EXTRACT` function returns the captured substring if there is a capturing group.